# Processing : change saturation of a picture

Tags: processing

I have to use Processing for a project and I would change the saturation of a picture (more precisely a photo).
I know that I can use `colorMode(HSB, 255)` then change the saturation with `tint(x, mySaturation, 255)`, but this method force to choose also the hue (the x), so the picture will be entirely red or green or any other color of the color circle.

How can I juste change the saturation without change the hue ?

Thank you.

Comment: There are lots of hits for "processing change suturation". You should [edit] the question and show some of your research. For example, you get get the hue and save it for later use when setting the saturation, no?

Comment: I can't save the hue, it is a photo... :/

Answer (score 0):

Stack Overflow isn't really designed for general "how do I do this" type questions. It's for specific "I tried X, expected Y, but got Z instead" type questions. But I'll try to help in a general sense:

You need to [break your problem down into smaller pieces](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program) and then take those pieces on one at a time. Get something simple working.

Can you write a simple sketch that gets the RGB value of a single pixel in an image? The `PImage.get()` function is your friend here. Work your way forward in small steps. Can you iterate over every pixel of the image and draw that to the screen to recreate the image?

When you have that working perfectly, then try to add code that uses HSB color mode. You're going to have to convert the RGB pixel values into HSB values. The `hue()`, `saturation()`, and `brightness()` functions are your friend here. Get your program working in HSB mode before moving on.

When you have that working perfectly, then it should be relatively straightforward to modify the saturation of each pixel.

If you get stuck, you can post a more specific question along with a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Good luck.